# Android: dynamic permission request design pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, permissions, android-permissions

I am quite new in android programming. I would like to ask about `startActivityForResult()` and `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` function and their design. I understand that result of those functions is handled by another Activity functions (`onActivityResult()` and `onRequestPermissionsResult()` respectively). But I don't understand why is it designed this way.

Especially with `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`. Why do I have to control if I have permission (`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`), if I don't then ask for it (`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`). And then handle in completely different function if I got this permission or not?

I would expect somethink like:

```
askPermission(Context context, String permission, Runnable permissionGranted, Runnable permissionDenied)
```

which would call permissionGranted if I already have permission or if I got it from user. With this function I would have to care just if I have permission or I don't have it.

Now I have to distunguish if I have permission and then do synchronous task or I don't have it and then do "asynchronous" task in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` where I very often do the same, as I do if I already have permission.

My question is: Is there some reason, why are permissions designed this way? Is there some funtion as I wrote above to allow me just say what to do if I have and what to do if i don't have permission (in functional way)? Or is there some desing pattern to easy handle permissions and starting activities for result?

Thanks for your time and some explanation if you know why is this design good.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Not a good way!

If we use inheritence concept we may solve this problem a little

we can make it synchronous like this :

```
//Kotlin
askForPermissions(permissionList, onPermissionsGranted = {
           //If permissions given
        }, onPermissionFailed = {
           //If permissions not given
        })
```

buy using inheritence :

```
//Kotlin
open class PermissionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val PERM_REQ_CODE = 1457
    private lateinit var onPermissionsGranted: () -> Unit;
    private lateinit var onPermissionFailed: () -> Unit;
    private lateinit var perms: Array<String>

    internal fun askForPermissions(perms: Array<String>, onPermissionsGranted: () -> Unit, onPermissionFailed: () -> Unit) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkIfOneNotHasPermission(perms)) {
                //Dont have permissions
                this.perms = perms
                this.onPermissionsGranted = onPermissionsGranted
                this.onPermissionFailed = onPermissionFailed
                requestPermissions(perms, PERM_REQ_CODE)
            }
        } else {
            onPermissionsGranted.invoke()
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun checkIfOneNotHasPermission(perms: Array<String>): Boolean {
        perms.forEach {
            if (checkSelfPermission(it) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERM_REQ_CODE -> {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkIfOneNotHasPermission(perms)) {
                        onPermissionFailed.invoke()
                    } else {
                        onPermissionsGranted.invoke()
                    }
                } else {
                    onPermissionsGranted.invoke()
                }
            }
            else -> {
                onPermissionFailed.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but do you have granted, there can't run more permission requests at one time? Basically, you have some queue of events processed by `Activity` and this is probably just another event. So if someone clicks button in you app before you get permission, it's going to be `race condition`. Am i wrong?

Comment: If you see that method, it takes list of permissions, so you can request multiple permissions. About race condition,it does not happen, because permission requests show as dialogs, so if you are trying to click or close that dialog onPermissionResult will be called with fail result.